# Passing an MessageTemplate String to a Serilog Wrapper

Tags: c#, serilog

I have a question.

I have the following code (in C#):

```
public static void Warning(string log)
{
    Serilog.Log.Warning(log);
}
```

I would like to pass in a value that looks like such:

```
Serilog.Log.Warning("Checked out order {0} for ${1:C}", order.Id, order.Total);
```

Is there any way to pass the interpolated string (and its parameters) from a wrapper around Serilog so that I can get the benefit of having a MessageTemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to have a single wrapper around `Log.Warning`, then the method should have a message and a params:

```cs
public static void Warning(string msg, params object[] args)
{
    Serilog.Log.Warning(msg, args);
}
```

Usage would then be:

```cs
MyLogWrapper.Warning("Checked out order {0} for ${1:C}", order.Id, order.Total);
```

Consider using named parameters in the message to take full advantage of the fully structured logging:

```cs
MyLogWrapper.Warning("Checked out order {OrderId} for ${OrderTotal:C}", order.Id, order.Total);
```